# How can I know if a Word list is a bullet list or a numeric list?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am reading a word document (converting it to HTML) and want to know what type each paragraph is (at least that's the way I think I want to do it like).

My code looks like this

```
Application application = new Application();
var doc = application.Documents.Open("D:\\myDoc.docx");

for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.ParagraphStyle.NameLocal}");
}
```

This outputs *Header 1*, *Normal* and *List Paragraph* for instance. So my question. I can't see if *List Paragraph* is a bullet list or a numeric list. Question, How can I know what type the list is of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Range.ListFormat.ListType` which can have the following values:

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies a type of list.
public enum WdListType
{
    // Summary:
    //     List with no bullets, numbering, or outlining.
    wdListNoNumbering = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     ListNum fields that can be used in the body of a paragraph.
    wdListListNumOnly = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Bulleted list.
    wdListBullet = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Simple numeric list.
    wdListSimpleNumbering = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Outlined list.
    wdListOutlineNumbering = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Mixed numeric list.
    wdListMixedNumbering = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Picture bulleted list.
    wdListPictureBullet = 6,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

It may not be enough to distinguis two Word lists.
I don't know what exactly means "Outlined list", but it appears that both numeric lists and bulleted lists are in this category.

So, what can you do?

**Option 1.** You can use `Range.ListFormat.ListString` to determine what text is marking the list. It can be bullet, number, triangle or anything that is defined in word file. But this is not very good idea because you never know what value is stored there so you can't compare it.

**Option 2.** You can use [WdListNumberStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837344.aspx) Enumeration, though it's a little bit complicated. I'll try to explain.
There is property called `Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels` which stores list formats for all possible levels of list. Usual lists have level 1 format and nested lists have formats from 2 to 9 respectively (seems like you can define 9 different formats for nested lists in MS Word). So, what you need is to get first item of `Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels` property and check its `NumberStyle` property (see link above). However since `ListLevels` supports only `IEnumerable` interface you can't get certain element. You can use something like this:

```
private static Word.WdListNumberStyle GetListType(Word.Range sentence)
{
    foreach (Word.ListLevel lvl in sentence.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels)
    {
        return lvl.NumberStyle;
    }
}
```

or, more specificly

```
private static Word.WdListNumberStyle GetListType(Word.Range sentence, byte level)
{
    foreach (Word.ListLevel lvl in sentence.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels)
    {
        if (level == 1)
            return lvl.NumberStyle;
        level--;
    }
}
```

I don't know whether it was helpful for the author of question but since I had a problem and while searching for solution I came here and didn't found one I decided to post what I found. I don't why it must be so complicated and why you can't get the value describing list style directly from `ListTemplate`.